# Unable to read the license file `LICENSE` for the spec `GoogleDataTransport (3.2.0)`

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

Unable to read the license file `LICENSE` for the spec `GoogleDataTransport (3.2.0)` when pod install Which result in GoogleDataTransport not found when try to build.

Earlier it worked but after I upload project to drive and from my windows computer I push to git and in another mac I cloned the repo and tried. That is the reason this happening.

I have tried cleaning pods, reinstalling updating, deleting podloc, pod directory and .xcworkspace. Non of them worked. I even copied the LICENSE file from another and pasted to GoogleDataTransport directory, nothing worked.

Answer (score 14):

I tried lot of things but nothing worked until I do these:

```
pod deintegrate
pod setup
pod install
```

in terminal. and open `.xcworkspace` and `Product -> Build`

This SO answer helped me for that: [How to clear or clean specific pod from the local cocoapods cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46428752/how-to-clear-or-clean-specific-pod-from-the-local-cocoapods-cache)

Comment: The answer is already here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090178/how-to-fix-pods-license-file-error so the Q&A was not needed, Happy new year BDW +1 . :)

Comment: Dude, just massive respect to you, I have literally spent an entire weekend trying to fix this issue before the deadline on Monday. And this is the only thing that has worked for me. You are my life savior.