# How to implement Phone Authentication with Firebase in a flutter project?

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am trying to implement and test phone authentication withe firebase in a flutter project. but it throws an error for the pod. Test it with Iphone 11 Pro Max.Confused and not able to find the pod error, kindly help to find the error and the solution needed at the particular line

> Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro Max in debug mode... Running
>   pod install...                                              5.2s
>   Running Xcode build... Xcode build done.
>   19.2s Failed to build iOS app Error output from Xcode build: ↳
>       2020-05-18 16:07:58.232 xcodebuild[40406:746075] warning:  The file reference for "Firebase.debug.xcconfig" is a member of multiple
>   groups ("Support Files" and "Support Files"); this indicates a
>   malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the groups will be
>   preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want
>   a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add
>   another reference to the same path.
>       2020-05-18 16:07:58.232 xcodebuild[40406:746075] warning:  The file reference for "Firebase.release.xcconfig" is a member of multiple
>   groups ("Support Files" and "Support Files"); this indicates a
>   malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the groups will be
>   preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want
>   a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add
>   another reference to the same path.
>       2020-05-18 16:07:58.238 xcodebuild[40406:746075] warning:  The file reference for "GoogleUtilities.debug.xcconfig" is a member of
>   multiple groups ("Support Files" and "Support Files"); this indicates
>   a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the groups will be
>   preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want
>   a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add
>   another reference to the same path.
>       2020-05-18 16:07:58.238 xcodebuild[40406:746075] warning:  The file reference for "GoogleUtilities.release.xcconfig" is a member of
>   multiple groups ("Support Files" and "Support Files"); this indicates
>   a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the groups will be
>   preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want
>   a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add
>   another reference to the same path.
>       ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> Xcode's output: ↳
>       /Users/tusharrai/AndroidStudioProjects/demo_flutter_app/ios/Pods/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics/Firebase/CoreDiagnostics/FIRCDLibrary/FIRCoreDiagnostics.m:25:9:
>   fatal error: 'GoogleUtilities/GULAppEnvironmentUtil.h' file not found
>       #import 
>               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       1 error generated.
>       note: Using new build system
>       note: Building targets in parallel
>       note: Planning build
>       note: Constructing build description
>       warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To
>   resolve this, select a development team in the Runner editor. (in
>   target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
>
> Could not build the application for the simulator. Error launching
>   application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.

pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  firebase_auth: ^0.16.0
```

podfile.lock

```
PODS:
  - Firebase/Analytics (3.6.0):
    - FirebaseAnalytics (= 3.4.2)
  - Firebase/Auth (6.22.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseAuth (~> 6.5.1)
  - Firebase/Core (3.6.0):
    - Firebase/Analytics
  - Firebase/CoreOnly (6.22.0):
    - FirebaseCore (= 6.6.6)
  - firebase_auth (0.0.1):
    - Firebase/Auth (~> 6.3)
    - Firebase/Core
    - Flutter
  - firebase_auth_web (0.1.0):
    - Flutter
  - firebase_core (0.0.1):
    - Firebase/Core
    - Flutter
  - firebase_core_web (0.1.0):
    - Flutter
  - FirebaseAnalytics (3.4.2):
    - FirebaseInstanceID (~> 1.0)
    - GoogleInterchangeUtilities (~> 1.2)
    - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.1)
    - GoogleUtilities (~> 1.2)
  - FirebaseAuth (6.5.3):
    - FirebaseAuthInterop (~> 1.0)
    - FirebaseCore (~> 6.6)
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 6.5)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 6.5)
    - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (~> 1.1)
  - FirebaseAuthInterop (1.1.0)
  - FirebaseCore (6.6.6):
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (~> 1.2)
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop (~> 1.2)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 6.5)
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger (~> 6.5)
  - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (1.3.0):
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop (~> 1.2)
    - GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport (~> 3.1)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 6.5)
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger (~> 6.5)
    - nanopb (~> 1.30905.0)
  - FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop (1.2.0)
  - FirebaseInstanceID (1.0.9)
  - Flutter (1.0.0)
  - GoogleDataTransport (6.1.0)
  - GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport (3.1.0):
    - GoogleDataTransport (~> 6.1)
    - nanopb (~> 1.30905.0)
  - GoogleInterchangeUtilities (1.2.2):
    - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.1)
  - GoogleSymbolUtilities (1.1.2)
  - GoogleUtilities (1.3.2):
    - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.1)
  - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (6.6.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
    - GoogleUtilities/Network
  - GoogleUtilities/Environment (6.6.0):
    - PromisesObjC (~> 1.2)
  - GoogleUtilities/Logger (6.6.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment
  - GoogleUtilities/Network (6.6.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib"
    - GoogleUtilities/Reachability
  - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (6.6.0)"
  - GoogleUtilities/Reachability (6.6.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (1.4.0)
  - nanopb (1.30905.0):
    - nanopb/decode (= 1.30905.0)
    - nanopb/encode (= 1.30905.0)
  - nanopb/decode (1.30905.0)
  - nanopb/encode (1.30905.0)
  - PromisesObjC (1.2.8)

DEPENDENCIES:
  - firebase_auth (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`)
  - firebase_auth_web (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth_web/ios`)
  - firebase_core (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`)
  - firebase_core_web (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core_web/ios`)
  - Flutter (from `Flutter`)

SPEC REPOS:
  trunk:
    - Firebase
    - FirebaseAnalytics
    - FirebaseAuth
    - FirebaseAuthInterop
    - FirebaseCore
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop
    - FirebaseInstanceID
    - GoogleDataTransport
    - GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport
    - GoogleInterchangeUtilities
    - GoogleSymbolUtilities
    - GoogleUtilities
    - GTMSessionFetcher
    - nanopb
    - PromisesObjC

EXTERNAL SOURCES:
  firebase_auth:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios"
  firebase_auth_web:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth_web/ios"
  firebase_core:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios"
  firebase_core_web:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/firebase_core_web/ios"
  Flutter:
    :path: Flutter

SPEC CHECKSUMS:
  Firebase: 32f9520684e87c7af3f0704f7f88042626d6b536
  firebase_auth: f8287325aae894aff045dff38bf0667cbeb49563
  firebase_auth_web: 0955c07bcc06e84af76b9d4e32e6f31518f2d7de
  firebase_core: 0d8be0e0d14c4902953aeb5ac5d7316d1fe4b978
  firebase_core_web: d501d8b946b60c8af265428ce483b0fff5ad52d1
  FirebaseAnalytics: 3f5358d9104adf159cc8d99b7b501e50099a39ad
  FirebaseAuth: 7047aec89c0b17ecd924a550c853f0c27ac6015e
  FirebaseAuthInterop: a0f37ae05833af156e72028f648d313f7e7592e9
  FirebaseCore: 9aca0f1fffb405176ba15311a5621fcde4106fcf
  FirebaseCoreDiagnostics: 4a773a47bd83bbd5a9b1ccf1ce7caa8b2d535e67
  FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop: 296e2c5f5314500a850ad0b83e9e7c10b011a850
  FirebaseInstanceID: 2d0518b1378fe9d685ef40cbdd63d2fdc1125339
  Flutter: 0e3d915762c693b495b44d77113d4970485de6ec
  GoogleDataTransport: f6f8eba931df03ebd2232ff4645aa85f8f47b5ab
  GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport: d70a561f7d236af529fee598835caad5e25f6d3d
  GoogleInterchangeUtilities: d5bc4d88d5b661ab72f9d70c58d02ca8c27ad1f7
  GoogleSymbolUtilities: 631ee17048aa5e9ab133470d768ea997a5ef9b96
  GoogleUtilities: 39530bc0ad980530298e9c4af8549e991fd033b1
  GTMSessionFetcher: 6f5c8abbab8a9bce4bb3f057e317728ec6182b10
  nanopb: c43f40fadfe79e8b8db116583945847910cbabc9
  PromisesObjC: c119f3cd559f50b7ae681fa59dc1acd19173b7e6

PODFILE CHECKSUM: c34e2287a9ccaa606aeceab922830efb9a6ff69a

COCOAPODS: 1.9.1
```

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52398521/flutter-ios-build-failure-error-with-multiple-commands-after-the-xcode-upgrade

Comment: `[!] Unable to read the license file LICENSE for the spec Firebase (6.22.0)` now the error goes to this, can you help

Comment: I'm having the exact issue. Have you solved? @TusharRai

Comment: Yes solved this by uncommenting and activating the code `platform: ios, '9.0'` in pod file, but stucked in another error.

Comment: Try this my friend and upvote my comment if it solves your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59547862/unable-to-read-the-license-file-license-for-the-spec-googledatatransport-3-2