# How to reslove Firebase authentication Pod error in a flutter project?

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

Implementing firebase phone authentication in a flutter project, throws an error with pod.

> pod install Analyzing dependencies Downloading dependencies
>   Installing Firebase 3.6.0 Installing Firebase 6.22.0 (was 3.6.0)
>   Installing GoogleUtilities 1.3.2 (source changed to
>   `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/` from `trunk`) Installing GoogleUtilities
>   6.6.0 (was 1.3.2 and source changed to `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/` from `trunk`) Generating Pods project Integrating client project Pod
>   installation complete! There are 5 dependencies from the Podfile and
>   23 total pods installed.
>
> [!] Unable to read the license file `LICENSE` for the spec `Firebase
>   (6.22.0)`
>
> [!] Unable to read the license file `GoogleUtilities/LICENSE` for the
>   spec `GoogleUtilities (6.6.0)`
>
> [!] Unable to read the license file `LICENSE` for the spec `Firebase
>   (6.22.0)`
>
> [!] Unable to read the license file `GoogleUtilities/LICENSE` for the
>   spec `GoogleUtilities (6.6.0)`
>
> [!] [Xcodeproj] Generated duplicate UUIDs:
>
> PBXFileReference --
>   Pods.xcodeproj/mainGroup/children/children:children:|,|,displayName:Firebase,isa:PBXGroup,name:Firebase,path:Firebase,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,displayName:FirebaseAnalytics,isa:PBXGroup,name:FirebaseAnalytics,path:FirebaseAnalytics,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:FirebaseAuth,isa:PBXGroup,name:FirebaseAuth,path:FirebaseAuth,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,displayName:FirebaseAuthInterop,isa:PBXGroup,name:FirebaseAuthInterop,path:FirebaseAuthInterop,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:FirebaseCore,isa:PBXGroup,name:FirebaseCore,path:FirebaseCore,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,|,|,displayName:FirebaseCoreDiagnostics,isa:PBXGroup,name:FirebaseCoreDiagnostics,path:FirebaseCoreDiagnostics,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,|,displayName:FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop,isa:PBXGroup,name:FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop,path:FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,displayName:FirebaseInstanceID,isa:PBXGroup,name:FirebaseInstanceID,path:FirebaseInstanceID,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,displayName:GTMSessionFetcher,isa:PBXGroup,name:GTMSessionFetcher,path:GTMSessionFetcher,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:GoogleDataTransport,isa:PBXGroup,name:GoogleDataTransport,path:GoogleDataTransport,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport,isa:PBXGroup,name:GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport,path:GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,displayName:GoogleInterchangeUtilities,isa:PBXGroup,name:GoogleInterchangeUtilities,path:GoogleInterchangeUtilities,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,displayName:GoogleSymbolUtilities,isa:PBXGroup,name:GoogleSymbolUtilities,path:GoogleSymbolUtilities,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,displayName:GoogleUtilities,isa:PBXGroup,name:GoogleUtilities,path:GoogleUtilities,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:PromisesObjC,isa:PBXGroup,name:PromisesObjC,path:PromisesObjC,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:nanopb,isa:PBXGroup,name:nanopb,path:nanopb,sourceTree:,,displayName:Pods,isa:PBXGroup,name:Pods,sourceTree:,/Pods/children/children:children:|,displayName:Analytics,isa:PBXGroup,name:Analytics,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,|,|,displayName:Support
>   Files,isa:PBXGroup,name:Support Files,path:../Target Support
>   Files/Firebase,sourceTree:,,displayName:Firebase,isa:PBXGroup,name:Firebase,path:Firebase,sourceTree:,/Pods/Firebase/children/children:displayName:Firebase.debug.xcconfig,includeInIndex:1,isa:PBXFileReference,lastKnownFileType:text.xcconfig,path:Firebase.debug.xcconfig,sourceTree:,,displayName:Firebase.release.xcconfig,includeInIndex:1,isa:PBXFileReference,lastKnownFileType:text.xcconfig,path:Firebase.release.xcconfig,sourceTree:,,displayName:Firebase.debug.xcconfig,includeInIndex:1,isa:PBXFileReference,lastKnownFileType:text.xcconfig,path:Firebase.debug.xcconfig,sourceTree:,,displayName:Firebase.release.xcconfig,includeInIndex:1,isa:PBXFileReference,lastKnownFileType:text.xcconfig,path:Firebase.release.xcconfig,sourceTree:,,displayName:Support
>   Files,isa:PBXGroup,name:Support Files,path:../Target Support
>   Files/Firebase,sourceTree:,/Pods/Firebase/Support
>   Files/children/displayName:Firebase.debug.xcconfig,includeInIndex:1,isa:PBXFileReference,lastKnownFileType:text.xcconfig,path:Firebase.debug.xcconfig,sourceTree:,/Pods/Firebase/Support
>   Files/Firebase.debug.xcconfig PBXFileReference --
>   Pods.xcodeproj/mainGroup/children/children:children:|,|,displayName:Firebase,isa:PBXGroup,name:Firebase,path:Firebase,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,displayName:FirebaseAnalytics,isa:PBXGroup,name:FirebaseAnalytics,path:FirebaseAnalytics,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:FirebaseAuth,isa:PBXGroup,name:FirebaseAuth,path:FirebaseAuth,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,displayName:FirebaseAuthInterop,isa:PBXGroup,name:FirebaseAuthInterop,path:FirebaseAuthInterop,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:FirebaseCore,isa:PBXGroup,name:FirebaseCore,path:FirebaseCore,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,|,|,displayName:FirebaseCoreDiagnostics,isa:PBXGroup,name:FirebaseCoreDiagnostics,path:FirebaseCoreDiagnostics,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,|,displayName:FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop,isa:PBXGroup,name:FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop,path:FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,displayName:FirebaseInstanceID,isa:PBXGroup,name:FirebaseInstanceID,path:FirebaseInstanceID,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,displayName:GTMSessionFetcher,isa:PBXGroup,name:GTMSessionFetcher,path:GTMSessionFetcher,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:GoogleDataTransport,isa:PBXGroup,name:GoogleDataTransport,path:GoogleDataTransport,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport,isa:PBXGroup,name:GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport,path:GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,displayName:GoogleInterchangeUtilities,isa:PBXGroup,name:GoogleInterchangeUtilities,path:GoogleInterchangeUtilities,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,displayName:GoogleSymbolUtilities,isa:PBXGroup,name:GoogleSymbolUtilities,path:GoogleSymbolUtilities,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,displayName:GoogleUtilities,isa:PBXGroup,name:GoogleUtilities,path:GoogleUtilities,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:PromisesObjC,isa:PBXGroup,name:PromisesObjC,path:PromisesObjC,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:nanopb,isa:PBXGroup,name:nanopb,path:nanopb,sourceTree:,,displayName:Pods,isa:PBXGroup,name:Pods,sourceTree:,/Pods/children/children:children:|,displayName:Analytics,isa:PBXGroup,name:Analytics,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,|,|,displayName:Support
>   Files,isa:PBXGroup,name:Support Files,path:../Target Support
>   Files/Firebase,sourceTree:,,displayName:Firebase,isa:PBXGroup,name:Firebase,path:Firebase,sourceTree:,/Pods/Firebase/children/children:displayName:Firebase.debug.xcconfig,includeInIndex:1,isa:PBXFileReference,lastKnownFileType:text.xcconfig,path:Firebase.debug.xcconfig,sourceTree:,,displayName:Firebase.release.xcconfig,includeInIndex:1,isa:PBXFileReference,lastKnownFileType:text.xcconfig,path:Firebase.release.xcconfig,sourceTree:,,displayName:Firebase.debug.xcconfig,includeInIndex:1,isa:PBXFileReference,lastKnownFileType:text.xcconfig,path:Firebase.debug.xcconfig,sourceTree:,,displayName:Firebase.release.xcconfig,includeInIndex:1,isa:PBXFileReference,lastKnownFileType:text.xcconfig,path:Firebase.release.xcconfig,sourceTree:,,displayName:Support
>   Files,isa:PBXGroup,name:Support Files,path:../Target Support
>   Files/Firebase,sourceTree:,/Pods/Firebase/Support
>   Files/children/displayName:Firebase.release.xcconfig,includeInIndex:1,isa:PBXFileReference,lastKnownFileType:text.xcconfig,path:Firebase.release.xcconfig,sourceTree:,/Pods/Firebase/Support
>   Files/Firebase.release.xcconfig PBXFileReference --
>   Pods.xcodeproj/mainGroup/children/children:children:|,|,displayName:Firebase,isa:PBXGroup,name:Firebase,path:Firebase,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,displayName:FirebaseAnalytics,isa:PBXGroup,name:FirebaseAnalytics,path:FirebaseAnalytics,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:FirebaseAuth,isa:PBXGroup,name:FirebaseAuth,path:FirebaseAuth,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,displayName:FirebaseAuthInterop,isa:PBXGroup,name:FirebaseAuthInterop,path:FirebaseAuthInterop,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:FirebaseCore,isa:PBXGroup,name:FirebaseCore,path:FirebaseCore,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,|,|,displayName:FirebaseCoreDiagnostics,isa:PBXGroup,name:FirebaseCoreDiagnostics,path:FirebaseCoreDiagnostics,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,|,displayName:FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop,isa:PBXGroup,name:FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop,path:FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,displayName:FirebaseInstanceID,isa:PBXGroup,name:FirebaseInstanceID,path:FirebaseInstanceID,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,displayName:GTMSessionFetcher,isa:PBXGroup,name:GTMSessionFetcher,path:GTMSessionFetcher,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:GoogleDataTransport,isa:PBXGroup,name:GoogleDataTransport,path:GoogleDataTransport,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport,isa:PBXGroup,name:GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport,path:GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,displayName:GoogleInterchangeUtilities,isa:PBXGroup,name:GoogleInterchangeUtilities,path:GoogleInterchangeUtilities,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,displayName:GoogleSymbolUtilities,isa:PBXGroup,name:GoogleSymbolUtilities,path:GoogleSymbolUtilities,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,displayName:GoogleUtilities,isa:PBXGroup,name:GoogleUtilities,path:GoogleUtilities,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:PromisesObjC,isa:PBXGroup,name:PromisesObjC,path:PromisesObjC,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:nanopb,isa:PBXGroup,name:nanopb,path:nanopb,sourceTree:,,displayName:Pods,isa:PBXGroup,name:Pods,sourceTree:,/Pods/children/children:children:|,displayName:Frameworks,isa:PBXGroup,name:Frameworks,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,|,|,displayName:Support
>   Files,isa:PBXGroup,name:Support Files,path:../Target Support
>   Files/GoogleUtilities,sourceTree:,,displayName:GoogleUtilities,isa:PBXGroup,name:GoogleUtilities,path:GoogleUtilities,sourceTree:,/Pods/GoogleUtilities/children/children:displayName:GoogleUtilities.debug.xcconfig,includeInIndex:1,isa:PBXFileReference,lastKnownFileType:text.xcconfig,path:GoogleUtilities.debug.xcconfig,sourceTree:,,displayName:GoogleUtilities.release.xcconfig,includeInIndex:1,isa:PBXFileReference,lastKnownFileType:text.xcconfig,path:GoogleUtilities.release.xcconfig,sourceTree:,,displayName:GoogleUtilities.debug.xcconfig,includeInIndex:1,isa:PBXFileReference,lastKnownFileType:text.xcconfig,path:GoogleUtilities.debug.xcconfig,sourceTree:,,displayName:GoogleUtilities.release.xcconfig,includeInIndex:1,isa:PBXFileReference,lastKnownFileType:text.xcconfig,path:GoogleUtilities.release.xcconfig,sourceTree:,,displayName:Support
>   Files,isa:PBXGroup,name:Support Files,path:../Target Support
>   Files/GoogleUtilities,sourceTree:,/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Support
>   Files/children/displayName:GoogleUtilities.debug.xcconfig,includeInIndex:1,isa:PBXFileReference,lastKnownFileType:text.xcconfig,path:GoogleUtilities.debug.xcconfig,sourceTree:,/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Support
>   Files/GoogleUtilities.debug.xcconfig PBXFileReference --
>   Pods.xcodeproj/mainGroup/children/children:children:|,|,displayName:Firebase,isa:PBXGroup,name:Firebase,path:Firebase,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,displayName:FirebaseAnalytics,isa:PBXGroup,name:FirebaseAnalytics,path:FirebaseAnalytics,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:FirebaseAuth,isa:PBXGroup,name:FirebaseAuth,path:FirebaseAuth,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,displayName:FirebaseAuthInterop,isa:PBXGroup,name:FirebaseAuthInterop,path:FirebaseAuthInterop,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:FirebaseCore,isa:PBXGroup,name:FirebaseCore,path:FirebaseCore,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,|,|,displayName:FirebaseCoreDiagnostics,isa:PBXGroup,name:FirebaseCoreDiagnostics,path:FirebaseCoreDiagnostics,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,|,displayName:FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop,isa:PBXGroup,name:FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop,path:FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,displayName:FirebaseInstanceID,isa:PBXGroup,name:FirebaseInstanceID,path:FirebaseInstanceID,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,displayName:GTMSessionFetcher,isa:PBXGroup,name:GTMSessionFetcher,path:GTMSessionFetcher,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:GoogleDataTransport,isa:PBXGroup,name:GoogleDataTransport,path:GoogleDataTransport,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport,isa:PBXGroup,name:GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport,path:GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,displayName:GoogleInterchangeUtilities,isa:PBXGroup,name:GoogleInterchangeUtilities,path:GoogleInterchangeUtilities,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,displayName:GoogleSymbolUtilities,isa:PBXGroup,name:GoogleSymbolUtilities,path:GoogleSymbolUtilities,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,displayName:GoogleUtilities,isa:PBXGroup,name:GoogleUtilities,path:GoogleUtilities,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:PromisesObjC,isa:PBXGroup,name:PromisesObjC,path:PromisesObjC,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:nanopb,isa:PBXGroup,name:nanopb,path:nanopb,sourceTree:,,displayName:Pods,isa:PBXGroup,name:Pods,sourceTree:,/Pods/children/children:children:|,displayName:Frameworks,isa:PBXGroup,name:Frameworks,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,|,|,displayName:Support
>   Files,isa:PBXGroup,name:Support Files,path:../Target Support
>   Files/GoogleUtilities,sourceTree:,,displayName:GoogleUtilities,isa:PBXGroup,name:GoogleUtilities,path:GoogleUtilities,sourceTree:,/Pods/GoogleUtilities/children/children:displayName:GoogleUtilities.debug.xcconfig,includeInIndex:1,isa:PBXFileReference,lastKnownFileType:text.xcconfig,path:GoogleUtilities.debug.xcconfig,sourceTree:,,displayName:GoogleUtilities.release.xcconfig,includeInIndex:1,isa:PBXFileReference,lastKnownFileType:text.xcconfig,path:GoogleUtilities.release.xcconfig,sourceTree:,,displayName:GoogleUtilities.debug.xcconfig,includeInIndex:1,isa:PBXFileReference,lastKnownFileType:text.xcconfig,path:GoogleUtilities.debug.xcconfig,sourceTree:,,displayName:GoogleUtilities.release.xcconfig,includeInIndex:1,isa:PBXFileReference,lastKnownFileType:text.xcconfig,path:GoogleUtilities.release.xcconfig,sourceTree:,,displayName:Support
>   Files,isa:PBXGroup,name:Support Files,path:../Target Support
>   Files/GoogleUtilities,sourceTree:,/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Support
>   Files/children/displayName:GoogleUtilities.release.xcconfig,includeInIndex:1,isa:PBXFileReference,lastKnownFileType:text.xcconfig,path:GoogleUtilities.release.xcconfig,sourceTree:,/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Support
>   Files/GoogleUtilities.release.xcconfig
>
> [!] [Xcodeproj] Generated duplicate UUIDs:
>
> PBXAggregateTarget -- 072CEA044D2EF26F03496D5996BBF59F
>   PBXAggregateTarget -- 8D7F5D5DD528D21A72DC87ADA5B12E2D
>
> [!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project
>   because your project already has a custom config set. In order for
>   CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base
>   configurations of the target `Runner` to `Target Support
>   Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` or include the `Target
>   Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` in your build
>   configuration (`Flutter/Release.xcconfig`).

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090178/how-to-fix-pods-license-file-error